# How can I remove the first 23 characters from every line in atom editor?

Tags: regex, atom-editor

How can I remove the first 23 characters from every line in atom editor?

Thanks

```
0,0:10:49.25,0:10:51.00This is incredible, little brother!
0,0:10:52.38,0:10:54.58I never thought it would work so well.
0,0:10:56.92,0:11:01.08Yes, it's more than\N I ever imagined, big brother.
0,0:11:02.96,0:11:06.00My goal was to become\N the strongest man in the world.
0,0:11:08.13,0:11:09.42The strongest man.
0,0:11:10.04,0:11:11.42That was my dream.
0,0:11:14.21,0:11:18.21At last, the ultimate steroid,\N "Biceps King," is complete!
0,0:11:20.13,0:11:21.88Little brother!
0,0:11:21.92,0:11:24.96Drink this and you will obtain\N the power you've been seeking!
0,0:11:26.08,0:11:28.29What? Drink that?
0,0:11:28.79,0:11:32.67Indeed! I added strawberry flavoring,\N to make it go down easier.
0,0:11:33.50,0:11:34.50Brother...
0,0:11:41.21,0:11:43.42Yes, this will do!
0,0:11:45.04,0:11:47.29My brains and your brawn!
0,0:11:47.33,0:11:50.58By combining the greatest of minds\N and the strongest of bodies,
0,0:11:50.79,0:11:55.13we brothers will conquer everything\N on earth
0,0:11:55.17,0:11:56.67and rule as kings!
0,0:12:04.04,0:12:06.08I-Incredible!
```

Comment: Doesn't replacing `^.{23}` with empty string works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

text is disturbing...

from atom documentation:

ctrl-x ( start recording

ctrl-x ) stop recording

ctrl-x e execute macro

ctrl-x ctrl-e execute macro N times

ctrl-x b execute macro to the end of file

ctrl-x ctrl-b execute macro from the beginning to the end of file

source: https://atom.io/packages/atom-keyboard-macros

Use a macro that goes to the head of the line, delete 23 characters, and goes down a line. then execute to the end of the file.

Plus you can do as pushpesh-kumar-rajwanshi says and replace `.*{23}` with empty strings.